# What does the .'* operator mean in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, operators

What does the .'* operator mean in Matlab?

For example:

```
n1=0:30;
n2=1:30;
x1=sin((pi/4)*n1);
x2=cos((pi/7)*n2);
x1.'*x2
```

I know that .* means elementwise multiplication, - so do x1.'*x2 mean Elementwise multiplication with it conjugate?

Comment: Consider accepting the answer (and all the other answers to your questions) if any of them helped you, this way, future people will now if something is correct. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: basically it is doing `kron(x1.',x2)` or some call it outer product or dyadic product or rank-1 product or many many other equally boring names

Comment: This is an example of MATLAB's gross misuse/overuse of the "." to do radically different things.  One of my favorite examples is, for two compatible matrices `a` and `b`,  compare `a*2.0/b` with `a*2./b`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those are 2 operators. The first one `.'` is the [transpose](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html) of a matrix. Usually you may see it as `'` alone, but that gives the [complex conjugate transpose](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html) of a matrix, that for real numbers is the transpose. The second operator is the [matrix multiplication operator](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mtimes.html) `*`.

Basically your code creates 2 different vectors and then computes all possible permutations of multiplications between them.

Comment: Yes, +1. See also help/documentation for `ctranspose` and `transpose`.

Comment: Might also want to disambiguate `.'` from `'` since the complex conjugate is often confused and used wrongly.